# how to give a class to an <li> element that inserted in my code automatically by moodle cashe?

Tags: html, css, moodle

I am creating a new **moodle block** and I want to edit the code of CSS for this block. Currently there are images that I want to make inline **but moodle makes these images in ul and li by default** that take the full width "display: block". I can't give any class to these li and I can't select the li because moodle create the li tags for the titles and everything in the block, so if I edit the li it will be for every element like h1 and so on not only for imgs, can I give a class for it?

```
<ul class="unlist">
   <li class="r0"><div class="column c1"><h3><div class="text_to_html">User grade</div></h3></div></li>
   <li class="r1"><div class="column c1">first grade middle school </div></li>
   <li class="r0"><div class="column c1"><h3><div class="text_to_html">user type</div></h3></div></li>
   <li class="r1"><div class="column c1"> Student</div></li>
   <li class="r0"><div class="column c1"><h3><div class="text_to_html">General Certificates</div></h3></div></li>
   <li class="r1"><div class="column c1"><a download="download" class="inline" href="http://81.10.36.53/pluginfile.php/711/profilefield_file/files_2/0/1900 $10000 Gold Certificate both sides.jpg"><img class="cvpic" src="http://81.10.36.53/pluginfile.php/711/profilefield_file/files_2/0/1900%20%2410000%20Gold%20Certificate%20both%20sides.jpg"></a></div></li>
   <li class="r0"><div class="column c1"><a download="download" class="inline" href="http://81.10.36.53/pluginfile.php/711/profilefield_file/files_2/0/Aamir Javed Certificate.jpg"><img class="cvpic" src="http://81.10.36.53/pluginfile.php/711/profilefield_file/files_2/0/Aamir%20Javed%20Certificate.jpg"></a></div></li>
   <li class="r1"><div class="column c1"><a download="download" class="inline" href="http://81.10.36.53/pluginfile.php/711/profilefield_file/files_2/0/US $20 1905 Gold Certificate.jpg"><img class="cvpic" src="http://81.10.36.53/pluginfile.php/711/profilefield_file/files_2/0/US%20%2420%201905%20Gold%20Certificate.jpg"></a></div></li>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.unlist li div img").css("display", "inline");
});
```

What does it do:

- Wait for the page to completely load
- Select all `<img>` tags inside your `<ul>` that have the `unlist` class, that also have a `<div>` as a parent element, inside a `<li>` element

So, basically, it selects the `<img>` in the last 3 rows of the few lines you provided.

That way, you only select the `<li>` that have a `<img>` tag in it and not the other `<li>` with the `<h3>` tag, for example.

If you can't use jQuery, here is the same code, but in pure JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    document.querySelector("ul.unlist li div img").style.display = "inline";
})();
```

**Edit**

By re-reading your question, you want to add a class, so here it is:

**jQuery**

```
$("ul.unlist li div img").addClass("your-class");
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelector("ul.unlist li div img").className += " your-class";
```

Don't forget the space in the beginning of the JavaScript one, otherwise your `<img>` classes are gonna be like that : `cvpicyour-class` instead of `cvpic your-class`